How to search by Xpath using VBA with MSXML2?
I want to get elements from a website using XPath expressions. I'm using the built-in Microsoft library MSXML2 to do it, but doesn´t have a getElementByXpath() method. I've found this very good function getXPathElement() shown below to get element by Xpath in this old thread and it works fine only with full xpath expressions, but I need to find elements by Xpath that contains some text.
For example, if I want to get the element that contains the text HTML Editors from the url https://www.w3schools.com/html/, the full Xpath = "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/a[3]" but one option of Xpath based on a text could be Xpath = "//a[text()[contains(.,'HTML Editors')]]"
With this second XPath, the function fails. Is there a way to find this kind of Xpath expressions?
BTW: I know that Selenium has FindByXpath option, but for what I've seen, that implies install Selenium driver in a tricky way since there is no a direct binding for VBA and if possible I'd like to avoid install other things due to policy security reasons in the office.
This is my current code:
Sub Main()
Dim url As String
Dim oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim elem As HTMLBaseElement


    url = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/"
    oHttp.Open "GET", url, False
    oHttp.send
    
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = oHttp.responseText
    Set elem = getXPathElement("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/a[3]", html)

    ' ### with this xpath doesn´t work
    'Set elem = getXPathElement("//a[text()[contains(.,'HTML Editors')]]", html) 

    Debug.Print elem.innerText
    
End Sub

Public Function getXPathElement(sXPath As String, objElement As Object) As HTMLBaseElement
     Dim sXPathArray() As String
 
    Dim sNodeName As String
     Dim sNodeNameIndex As String
     Dim sRestOfXPath As String
     Dim lNodeIndex As Long
     Dim lCount As Long
 
    ' Split the xpath statement
     sXPathArray = Split(sXPath, "/")
     sNodeNameIndex = sXPathArray(1)
     If Not InStr(sNodeNameIndex, "[") > 0 Then
         sNodeName = sNodeNameIndex
         lNodeIndex = 1
     Else
         sXPathArray = Split(sNodeNameIndex, "[")
         sNodeName = sXPathArray(0)
         lNodeIndex = CLng(Left(sXPathArray(1), Len(sXPathArray(1)) - 1))
     End If
     sRestOfXPath = Right(sXPath, Len(sXPath) - (Len(sNodeNameIndex) + 1))
 
    Set getXPathElement = Nothing
     For lCount = 0 To objElement.ChildNodes().Length - 1
         If UCase(objElement.ChildNodes().Item(lCount).nodeName) = UCase(sNodeName) Then
             If lNodeIndex = 1 Then
                 If sRestOfXPath = "" Then
                     Set getXPathElement = objElement.ChildNodes().Item(lCount)
                 Else
                     Set getXPathElement = getXPathElement(sRestOfXPath, objElement.ChildNodes().Item(lCount))
                 End If
             End If
             lNodeIndex = lNodeIndex - 1
         End If
     Next lCount
 End Function

UPDATE
I've changed the code of Main macro using SelectNodes() based on the link shared by @SiebeJongebloed and I get the run-time error shown below. What I'm doing wrong?
Sub Main()
Dim url As String
Dim oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim elem As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode


    url = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/"
    oHttp.Open "GET", url, False
    oHttp.send
    
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    html.body.innerHTML = oHttp.responseText
    
    Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    doc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    doc.Load oHttp.responseText
    
    Set elem = doc.SelectNodes("//a[text()[contains(.,'HTML Editors')]")
    
End Sub



Have a look at selectNodes function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/msxml/use-contains-xpath-function

@SiebeJongebloed thanks for anwser, I´ve tried your suggestion, please check my update in original post.

As the error suggested add een extra ‘]‘ at the end. Every opening square bracket needs an closing square bracket.
So Change
//a[text()[contains(.,'HTML Editors')]

To
//a[text()[contains(.,'HTML Editors')]]


Is correct, I missed one ]. Now I added, but the error changes to run-time error 13 type mismatch

Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40750779/3710053

Sorry, my mistake.
If have found a great answer using Tidy:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12034126/3710053

I'll check that, thank you

No, in your shared last link, they are talking about c++ and VBScript. I haven´t found reference for VBA

Actually the source code of the HTML page on the URL is not well formed to use with the MSXML2.DOMDocument object. This is why you cannot achieve your goal.
You can check the error(s) with a similar code below;
Sub Test()
    Dim strURL As String, objHTTP As Object, XDoc As Object, myList As Object, Num As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim myStr As String
    strURL = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/"
    
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    
    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objHTTP.send
    
    Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    XDoc.async = False
    XDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    XDoc.validateOnParse = False
       
    XDoc.LoadXML (objHTTP.responseText)
    XDoc.Save (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Test.xml")
   
    Set myList = XDoc.SelectNodes("//a[contains(.,'HTML Editors')]")
    
    If XDoc.parseError.ErrorCode <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error at Line No: " & XDoc.parseError.Line & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error : " & XDoc.parseError.reason
        GoTo SafeExit:
    End If
    
    If myList.Length = 0 Then GoTo SafeExit:
   
SafeExit:
    If myList.Length = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Not found....", vbCritical, objHTTP.Status
    End If
    Set myList = Nothing
    Set XDoc = Nothing
    Set objHTTP = Nothing
End Sub

But if you would have a well formed HTML, you can use the "Contains" function with XPath as below;
    Sub Test2()
        Dim XDoc As Object, myList As Object
        Dim myStr As String
            
        Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
        XDoc.async = False
        XDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        XDoc.validateOnParse = False
        
        myStr = "<html> " & _
                   "<body> " & _
                       "<div>This is a division " & _
                          "<a  target='_top' href='default.asp'>HTML Home</a>" & _
                          "<a  target='_top' href='default.asp'>HTML Introduction</a> " & _
                          "<a  target='_top' href='default.asp'>HTML Editors</a> " & _
                          "<a  target='_top' href='default.asp'>HTML Basic</a>" & _
                       "</div> " & _
                       "<span class='color_h1'> HTML Tutorial</span>" & _
                   "</body>" & _
              "</html>"
                     
        XDoc.LoadXML (myStr)
        
        XDoc.Save (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Test.xml")
       
        Set myList = XDoc.SelectNodes("//a[contains(.,'HTML Editors')]")
        
        If XDoc.parseError.ErrorCode <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "Error at Line No: " & XDoc.parseError.Line & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Error : " & XDoc.parseError.reason
            GoTo SafeExit:
        End If
        
        If myList.Length = 0 Then GoTo SafeExit:
        
        MsgBox "Number of found items= " & myList.Length
        
        MsgBox "Found item: " & myList(0).Text
       
    SafeExit:
        If myList.Length = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Not found....", vbCritical
        End If
        Set myList = Nothing
        Set XDoc = Nothing
    End Sub



If no problems encountered, the XML file will be saved in the directory where the Excel file is in.

Thank you  for your answer and example. I've tried and it works the test2, but what do you mean by that HTML in the URL I shared is not well formed? That means is not possible to use URL with your solution?

I mean, the HTML source code of the URL is not well formed to be used with the MSXML2.DOMDocument object. When you load the "objHTTP.responseText" to the "MSXML2.DOMDocument" no errors should be encountered when parsed.
